# Dropdown layout issue (dropdown li's width bigger then head li)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble showing a drop down menu in the correct way. This is what I get to see:

[image]

This is my **HTML code**:

```
<nav class="menuBox">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="klassementen.html">KLASSEMENTEN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">KALENDER</a></li>
        <li><a href="nieuws.html">NIEUWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="media.html">MEDIA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="mijnteam.html">INLOGGEN</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="first">        
                    <a href="/app_dev.php/admin/dashboard">ADMIN</a>        
                </li>
                <li>        
                    <a href="/app_dev.php/user/edit">EDIT ACCOUNT</a>        
                </li>
                <li class="last">        
                    <a href="/app_dev.php/logout">LOG OUT</a>        
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My **CSS code**:

```
/* ### menu Box ### */
.menuBox { position: absolute; top: 74px; right: 2px; }
.menuBox ul { list-style: none; }
.menuBox li { float: left; margin-left: 17px; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; }
.menuBox li a { color: #3f3f3f; text-decoration: none; display: block; padding-bottom: 14px; }
.menuBox li a:hover { background: url(../images/menu_hover.png) repeat-x 0 bottom; }
.menuBox ul li ul{ display: none; }
.menuBox ul li:hover ul{  display: block; }
```

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

But how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your CSS:

```
.menuBox ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float:none;
}
```

Explanation: you're floating your `li` elements, but you need to clear the floats for the second level of `li` elements (those in the sub menus), thus you need to add this declaration.

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mkwdkjs3/)